# How to get list of childrens of children using xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

There is table element which have tr elements in them. While each tr element have td element in it.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> some data </td>
<td> other data </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I wanted to get the text from the td elements in pairs. But I am willing to do it with xpath.

So, I got the tr element from the lxml tree in one variable by applying xpath. Then applied xpath to get the td elements from that variable. But I get all td elements from table and I wanted to limit td elements from that variable only!

```
table = parsed.xpath("//table")
trElementFirst = table.xpath("/tr")[0]
tdElementsFromFirstTr = trElementFirst.xpath("/td")
```

I wanted to get list of td elements for only first tr element. But I get the list of all td elements from table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tdElementsFromFirstTr = trElementFirst.xpath("//td")` grabs all `td`

```
import lxml.html as html


htmlStr = '''<table>
<tr>
<td> some data </td>
<td> other data </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> NO </td>
<td> OTHER NO </td>
</tr>

</table>'''

parsed = html.fromstring(htmlStr)

table = parsed.xpath("//table")
trElementFirst = table[0].xpath("tr")[0]  
tdElementsFromFirstTr = trElementFirst.xpath("td")

for each in tdElementsFromFirstTr:
    print (each.text)
```

**Output:**

```
some data 
other data
```